# How to find $n$ in this equation? (involving modulus)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, simple-functions

How to find $n$ in this equation?

$10 \le (7n) \mod 24 \le 13$

Can I use program to solve this kind of equation?

Comment: If you are asking about generalizing to $c \leq a^b \leq d (\mod n)$, then I think this is a very difficult question : you may be able to use a program, but this is a variant of the discrete logarithm problem. In your case, it turns out  that $7^2 \equiv 1 \mod 24$, so you don't have many values of $n$ to check : only $7$ and $1$ appear as solutions of $7^n$ mod $24$, and none of these lie in the required range.

Comment: Yes, what I wanted is the generalization so I can find n on different variable value. Sorry if it's unclear

Comment: In that case, I think this not a logarithmic (in $n$) type problem, since it more difficult than the discrete logarithm problem.Since you have small numbers, writing a program give answers in short enough time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to solve $7n\equiv k \pmod {24}$ for $k=10,11,12,13$.  Just like in the reals you would like to multiply by the inverse of $7$.  As $7$ is coprime to $24$ you can find it.  You can generally use the Euclidean algorithm, but here we can do it by inspection.  We note that $7\cdot 3 \equiv -3 \pmod {24}$, so $1=7-2\cdot 3$ gives $7\cdot (1+2\cdot 3)=7\cdot 7 = 49 \equiv 1 \pmod {24}$ and $7$ is its own inverse.  Then $$7n \equiv 10 \pmod {24}\\n\equiv 7\cdot {10} \pmod {24}\\22 \equiv n \pmod {24}$$
and the others are similar.